# Converting number grade to letter grade - issue with displaying grade

Tags: javascript

I am having issues getting my code to run through the below if statements. I am taking an online class, and the only resources I have are the textbook. Help is appreciated. I am able to get it to return anything besides the prompt, error message and exit the program. It is correctly running a continuous loop.

```
var numberGrade;
var grade = [];
do {
    numberGrade = prompt("Enter number grade from 0 through 100\nOr enter -1 to end entries\n");
    numberGrade = parseInt(numberGrade);
    if (numberGrade >= 0 && numberGrade <= 100 ) {
        grade[grade.length] = numberGrade;
    } else if (numberGrade != -1) {
        alert("Entry not valid!\n Entry must be a valid number from 0 through 100 \n Or enter -1 to end entries");
    } 
    }
    while (numberGrade != -1);

for (var num = 0; num <= grade; num++) {
    if (grade >= 0 && grade <= 59) {
        alert ("Number grade =" + grade + "\nLetter Grade = F");
    }
    if (grade >= 60 && grade <= 62) {
             alert ("Number grade =" + numberGrade + "\nLetter Grade = D-");
        }
    if (grade >= 63 && grade <= 66) {
        alert ("Number grade =" + numberGrade + "\nLetter Grade = D");
    }
    if (numberGrade >= 67 && numberGrade <= 69) {
        alert ("Number grade =" + numberGrade + "\nLetter Grade = D+");
    }
    if (numberGrade >= 70 && numberGrade <= 76){
        alert ("Number grade =" + numberGrade + "\nLetter Grade = C");
    }
    if (numberGrade >= 77 && numberGrade <= 79) {
        alert ("Number grade =" + numberGrade + "\nLetter Grade = C+");
    }
    if (numberGrade >= 80 && numberGrade <= 82) {
        alert ("Number grade =" + numberGrade + "\nLetter Grade = B-");
    }
    if (numberGrade >= 83 && numberGrade <= 86) {
        alert ("Number grade =" + numberGrade + "\nLetter Grade = B");
    }
    else if (numberGrade >= 87 && numberGrade <= 89) {
        alert ("Number grade =" + numberGrade + "\nLetter Grade = B+");
    }
    if (numberGrade >= 90 && numberGrade <= 92) {
        alert ("Number grade =" + numberGrade + "\nLetter Grade = A-");
    }
    if (numberGrade >= 93 && numberGrade <= 100) {
        alert ("Number grade =" + numberGrade + "\nLetter Grade = A");
    }
}
```

Comment: `num <= grade` should be `num < grade.length`. And the `grade`s _and_ `numberGrade`s (you use both, inconsistently) in your `for` loop should all be `grade[num]`. And you should use `else if` for all but your first `if` conditions, just like you (randomly) used on your 9th one. Please see the documentation on [`for` loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for_statement) and try using the [debugging capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) of your browser.

Answer (score 2):

In your loop initialization, the statement `num <= grade` is meaningless because `grade` is an array and not a number.  Change your loop to `for (var num = 0; num < grade.length; num++)`. Then your `if` statements should test against elements of the `grade` array:

```
if (grade[num] >= 0 && grade[num] <= 59) {
    alert ("Number grade =" + grade[num] + "\nLetter Grade = F");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code a little bit to work properly. It can be done in better ways, but I chose to keep it simple so you can still understand it.

I created a function that converts the number grade to the letter, returning the string that you want to outputs.

```
var numberGrade;
do {
    numberGrade = prompt("Enter number grade from 0 through 100\nOr enter -1 to end entries\n");
    numberGrade = parseInt(numberGrade);

    if (numberGrade >= 0 && numberGrade <= 100 ) {
        // If the input is valid, calls the function and creates an alert with the return
        alert(convertGrade(numberGrade));
    } else if (numberGrade != -1) {
        alert("Entry not valid!\n Entry must be a valid number from 0 through 100 \n Or enter -1 to end entries");
    } 
} while (numberGrade != -1);

// Function that converts the grade, returning the message
function convertGrade(grade) {
    if (grade >= 0 && grade <= 59) {
        return ("Number grade =" + grade + "\nLetter Grade = F");
    }
    if (grade >= 60 && grade <= 62) {
        return ("Number grade =" + grade + "\nLetter Grade = D-");
    }
    if (grade >= 63 && grade <= 66) {
        return ("Number grade =" + grade + "\nLetter Grade = D");
    }
    if (grade>= 67 && grade <= 69) {
        return ("Number grade =" + grade + "\nLetter Grade = D+");
    }
    if (grade>= 70 && grade <= 76){
        return ("Number grade =" + grade + "\nLetter Grade = C");
    }
    if (grade>= 77 && grade <= 79) {
        return ("Number grade =" + grade + "\nLetter Grade = C+");
    }
    if (grade>= 80 && grade <= 82) {
        return ("Number grade =" + grade + "\nLetter Grade = B-");
    }
    if (grade>= 83 && grade <= 86) {
        return ("Number grade =" + grade + "\nLetter Grade = B");
    }
    if (grade>= 87 && grade <= 89) {
        return ("Number grade =" + grade + "\nLetter Grade = B+");
    }
    if (grade>= 90 && grade <= 92) {
        return ("Number grade =" + grade + "\nLetter Grade = A-");
    }
    if (grade>= 93 && grade <= 100) {
        return ("Number grade =" + grade + "\nLetter Grade = A");
    }
}
```